# How to open a record on a subgrid using easyrepro?

Tags: automated-tests, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, easyrepro

https://github.com/Microsoft/EasyRepro/issues/178

Hi all,

I am using dynamics365 version 9.x

Using EasyRepro I can navigate into an account via the global search and then also use the `xrmBrowser.Entity.ClickSubgridAddButton("foobar");` function to create a new record of that 'foobar' type. By doing this I know I am accessing the correct subgrid on the account record.

My question is....which function would I use to simply open up the record I have created. I have tried SelectSubgridLookup but I don't think that is the function I am looking for.

From the image you can see I have created the 'bonno bonno' contact but I cannot open the record using EasyRepro. any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/Microsoft/EasyRepro/issues/178

> Hello @darthtang - sorry for the delayed reply to your post here. From reviewing, it appears this is a feature gap and needs to be enhanced.
>
> While not ideal, if you wanted to open the record, you could try the following instead:
>
> ```
> xrmBrowser.Entity.ClickSubgridGridViewButton(subgridName)
> ```
>
> This should take you to the 'Associated View' via Related Navigation. From here, you could call:
>
> optional:
>
> `xrmbrowser.Related.Search(contactrecordname);`
>
> ```
> xrmBrowser.Related.OpenGridRow(#)
> ```
>
> At this point, you could then switch back to perform actions on the opened Contact entity record:
>
> ```
> xrmBrowser.Entity.SomeMethod();
> ```
>
> Please let me know if this set of steps help you with your scenario. I've added a feature enhancement to the backlog to allow opening of a record from a subgrid on a form.